# APN deviceToken to GCM deviceRegistrationId

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

My app registers for APNS push notifications and didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken get called with a deviceToken. I call Google GCM API's tokenWithAuthorizedEntity with the deviceToken to get a token for Google APIs. Can I use that token in the server as deviceRegistrationId when sending a push notification to the device (using GCM)? Or do I need to convert the Apple's deviceToken to a string and use that? The deviceToken is NSData, but GCM API requires a string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert deviceToken to string (NSString) as APNS recognizes its own device tokens only and not from any other services. Use this code:

```
NSString* newDeviceToken = [[[[deviceToken bytes]
                 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<" withString: @""] 
                stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @">" withString: @""] 
               stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];
```

Comment: I thought GCM keeps the actual deviceToken and returns a string reference to it (deviceRegistrationId). Have to say that Google's documentation about this is really poor.

Comment: See I can't comment on that since I work with iOS and don't really know much about GCM, but what I'm pretty sure about is that they work entirely different ways. You should be maybe looking into Apple docs instead of Google's docs.

Comment: I'm using GCM to send the notifications, so Apple docs don't tell how to use Apple token as Google deviceRegistrationId.

Comment: Let me clarify: Using GCM to send Push Notifications to Apple devices? Dude, if your answer to the above is yes, then you're in a hell lot of mess.

Comment: Yes, it makes it possible to use the same implementation on the server side for both Android and iOS. On the device side, it only requires a call to GCM library. This is not a mess, the only thing that is not clear is what id to use to identify the device where the notification should be sent.

Comment: In that case, it should be GCM deviceRegistrationId